# Compiling AngularJS app with animation module in yeoman gives unknown provider error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im having trouble compiling an angular app that uses the new animation service in Yeoman. Im using the *yo angular:app* generator.

Everything is fine when working uncompiled but as soon as I run *grunt build*. Once compiled an unknown provider error is given when I run the DIST folder. I believe it is because the animation service requires a class name, not a normal name. Anyone come across this or a fix?

I tried the usual dependancy rename so the compiler respects the naming but no luck.

Case 1:

```
angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate']).animation('.pageCube', function(){
// animation stuff
});

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- .pageCube-animation
```

Case 2:

```
angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate']).animation('.pageCube', ['.pageCube', function(){
// animation stuff
}]);

Error: $injector:unpr] Unknown provider: .pageCubeProvider <- .pageCube <- .pageCube-animation
```

Case 3: (never going to work but Provider is found)

```
angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate']).animation('pageCube', ['pageCube', function(){
// animation stuff
}]);

Error: [$animate:notcsel] Expecting class selector starting with '.' got 'pageCube'.
```

Notes
I am using: AngularJS v1.2.0-rc.2 which is further along than what yo angular:app installs. This might be something to keep in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Case 2 and 3 are completely wrong, the string after the [ is mainly needed as minify-safe option to function parameters so you would need a pageCube parameter on the function, but since you're far from this approach I guess you're doing something wrong inside the function